# draw method implementation in graphics2D class

Tags: java, awt, shapes, graphics2d

I desperately want to know the implementation of draw method in Graphics2D class.
I am actually looking for , how the draw method can draw a Shape.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question..

Answer (score 3):

grepcode is your [friend](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Graphics2D.java).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry, I have misunderstood the question. I thought OP wanted to know how to use draw in Graphics2D, but it seems that the question is more about how the draw method is implemented under-the-hood.

---

Oracle has a decent introductory [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) on this kind of thing.

For instance, to create a rectangle, your code would look something like this:

```
// draw Rectangle2D.Double
g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y,
                               rectwidth,
                               rectheight));
```

Comment: Yes exactly.I wanted to the draw method in graphics2D to draw a triangle too.

Comment: Something like  TriangleShape ts=new TriangleShape(parameters);  Graphics2D g2; g2.draw(ts); this should draw a triangle.

Comment: Ovals and Rectangles have built-in methods for them, but to do a triangle, you will just have to draw a generic polygon and define the points such that they form a triangle. This only requires some simple math/geometry!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

It explains some common algorithms for drawing lines. It's applied math to select what pixels must be painted in an optimized way.